Поиск одинаковых ключей в двух разных списках словарей PYTHON
Есть два списка по типу ({...}, {...}). В элементах обоих списков есть одинаковый ключ "name" который содержит строку. Пишу код который будет находить совпадения и записывать их в новый список строкой "значение1:значение2".
for name in own_cards:
   card = name['name']
   log.append(f'{count} {card}')
   for sub_name in rec_cards:
       sub_card = sub_name['name']
       if card == sub_card:
           print(f'{count} {card}:{sub_card}')
           log.append(f'{count} {card}:{sub_card}')
           references.append(f'{card}:{sub_card}')
           rec_cards.pop(rec_cards.index(sub_name))
           own_cards.pop(own_cards.index(name))
           count += 1
           break
       else :
           log.append(sub_card)

Не находит все одинаковые строки, лишь часть.
Результат есть, но не тот что ожидался. Из 140 элементов совпадают 30, хотя там намного больше совпадений. Ощущение, словно питон халтурит когда проводит поиск по индексу или при итерации. Ну не может строка "строка1" не совпасть со строкой "строка1". Гугл говорит обратиться к zip но это не то что мне нужно. Ветераны, помогите!
Пример вывода:
short_squeeze:short_squeeze
licence_japan:licence_japan
licence_turkey:licence_turkey
ceo:ceo
x:x
support_team:support_team
layerzero_listing:layerzero_listing
eth_pairs:eth_pairs
security_audition:security_audition
influencers:influencers

Список rec_cards:
[{'id': '2450', 'name': 'fan_tokens', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '26500'}, {'id': '2500', 'name': 'staking', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '19300'}, {'id': '2550', 'name': 'btc_pairs', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '6000'}, {'id': '2600', 'name': 'eth_pairs', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '1100'}, {'id': '2650', 'name': 'top_10_cmc_pairs', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '2700'}, {'id': '2700', 'name': 'gamefi_tokens', 'lvl': '17', 'price': '2000000'}, {'id': '2750', 'name': 'defi2.0_tokens', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '1300'}, {'id': '2800', 'name': 'socialfi_tokens', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '11900'}, {'id': '2850', 'name': 'meme_coins', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '2200'}, {'id': '2900', 'name': 'shit_coins', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '18700'}, {'id': '2950', 'name': 'margin_trading_x10', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '6600'}, {'id': '3000', 'name': 'margin_trading_x20', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '34800'}, {'id': '3050', 'name': 'margin_trading_x30', 'lvl': '8', 'price': '29900'}, {'id': '3100', 'name': 'margin_trading_x50', 'lvl': '14', 'price': '3300000'}, {'id': '3150', 'name': 'margin_trading_x75', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '178700'}, {'id': '3200', 'name': 'margin_trading_x100', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '119100'}, {'id': '3250', 'name': 'derivatives', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '13800'}, {'id': '3300', 'name': 'prediction_markets', 'lvl': '8', 'price': '15000'}, {'id': '3350', 'name': 'web3_integration', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '90500'}, {'id': '3400', 'name': 'dao', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '23800'}, {'id': '3450', 'name': 'p2p_trading', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '15700'}, {'id': '3500', 'name': 'trading_bots', 'lvl': '4', 'price': '4200'}, {'id': '3550', 'name': 'layerzero_listing', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '26500'}, {'id': '4500', 'name': 'ceo', 'lvl': '19', 'price': '26800000'}, {'id': '4600', 'name': 'marketing', 'lvl': '13', 'price': '159800'}, {'id': '4550', 'name': 'it_team', 'lvl': '15', 'price': '1500000'}, {'id': '2000', 'name': 'support_team', 'lvl': '15', 'price': '543800'}, {'id': '2050', 'name': 'hamsterbook', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '11900'}, {'id': '2200', 'name': 'hamstertube', 'lvl': '11', 'price': '25700'}, {'id': '2100', 'name': 'x', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '13100'}, {'id': '2150', 'name': 'cointelegraph', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '8300'}, {'id': '2250', 'name': 'hamstergram', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '11900'}, {'id': '2300', 'name': 'tiktok', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '17900'}, {'id': '2350', 'name': 'сoindesk', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '5500'}, {'id': '2400', 'name': 'influencers', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '59600'}, {'id': '4650', 'name': 'partnership_program', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '2800'}, {'id': '4700', 'name': 'product_team', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '2700'}, {'id': '4750', 'name': 'bisdev_team', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '1300'}, {'id': '4800', 'name': 'two_factor_authentication', 'lvl': '13', 'price': '159800'}, {'id': '4850', 'name': 'ux_and_ui_team', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '18100'}, {'id': '4900', 'name': 'security_team', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '23800'}, {'id': '4950', 'name': 'qa_team', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '7000'}, {'id': '5000', 'name': 'antihacking_shield', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '5300'}, {'id': '5050', 'name': 'risk_management_team', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '11000'}, {'id': '5100', 'name': 'security_audition', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '8000'}, {'id': '5150', 'name': 'anonymous_transactions_ban', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '12500'}, {'id': '5200', 'name': 'blocking_suspicious_accounts', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '4700'}, {'id': '5250', 'name': 'tokenomics_expert', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '13300'}, {'id': '5300', 'name': 'consensus_explorer_pass', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '93300'}, {'id': '5350', 'name': 'vc_labs', 'lvl': '11', 'price': '663300'}, {'id': '5400', 'name': 'compliance_officer', 'lvl': '2', 'price': '4500'}, {'id': '5450', 'name': 'welcome_to_amsterdam', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '8000'}, {'id': '5451', 'name': 'development_hub_mumbai', 'lvl': '2', 'price': '114900'}, {'id': '5452', 'name': 'data_сenter_tokyo', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '220500'}, {'id': '5251', 'name': 'leaderboards', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '22100'}, {'id': '5453', 'name': 'minigame', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '44100'}, {'id': '3600', 'name': 'kyc', 'lvl': '15', 'price': '72600'}, {'id': '3650', 'name': 'kyb', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '1300'}, {'id': '3700', 'name': 'legal_opinion', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '3700'}, {'id': '3750', 'name': 'sec_transparancy', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '28600'}, {'id': '3800', 'name': 'anti_money_loundering', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '71500'}, {'id': '3850', 'name': 'licence_uae', 'lvl': '15', 'price': '3600000'}, {'id': '3900', 'name': 'licence_europe', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '18700'}, {'id': '3950', 'name': 'licence_asia', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '13300'}, {'id': '4000', 'name': 'licence_south_america', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '13300'}, {'id': '4050', 'name': 'licence_australia', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '18700'}, {'id': '4100', 'name': 'licence_north_america', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '37300'}, {'id': '4150', 'name': 'licence_nigeria', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '4000'}, {'id': '4200', 'name': 'licence_japan', 'lvl': '3', 'price': '77600'}, {'id': '4250', 'name': 'licence_ethiopia', 'lvl': '3', 'price': '54300'}, {'id': '4300', 'name': 'licence_india', 'lvl': '3', 'price': '69800'}, {'id': '4350', 'name': 'licence_bangladesh', 'lvl': '2', 'price': '89300'}, {'id': '4400', 'name': 'licence_indonesia', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '110300'}, {'id': '4450', 'name': 'licence_vietnam', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '93700'}, {'id': '4452', 'name': 'licence_turkey', 'lvl': '2', 'price': '95700'}, {'id': '4453', 'name': 'licence_philippines', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '165400'}, {'id': '8000', 'name': 'dex', 'lvl': '2', 'price': '95700'}, {'id': '8500', 'name': 'oracle', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '19300'}, {'id': '9500', 'name': 'vesting_smartcontracts', 'lvl': '3', 'price': '63600'}, {'id': '5460', 'name': 'hamster_with_friends', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '5000'}, {'id': '5461', 'name': 'hamster_helps_whales', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '31000'}, {'id': '5462', 'name': 'vipassana_hamster', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '9000'}, {'id': '5463', 'name': 'university_hamster', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '23000'}, {'id': '5464', 'name': 'ton_listing_on_binance', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '90000'}, {'id': '5465', 'name': 'gym_hamster', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '12000'}, {'id': '5466', 'name': 'healthy_nutrition_hamster', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '17000'}, {'id': '5467', 'name': 'sleeping_hamster', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '15000'}, {'id': '5468', 'name': 'hamstergpt', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '55000'}, {'id': '5472', 'name': 'hamsterbank', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '300000'}, {'id': '5476', 'name': 'telegram_stars_integration', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '17000'}, {'id': '5478', 'name': 'telegram_miniapp_launch', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '66300'}, {'id': '5480', 'name': 'hamster_analytics', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '82700'}, {'id': '5481', 'name': '50m_telegram_channel', 'lvl': '4', 'price': '99000'}, {'id': '5483', 'name': 'apple_appstore_launch', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '252000'}, {'id': '5484', 'name': 'rolex_for_soulmate', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '1100000'}, {'id': '5485', 'name': 'call_for_btc_to_rise', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '5000000'}, {'id': '5487', 'name': 'business_jet', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '12000000'}, {'id': '5496', 'name': 'cx_hub_istanbul', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '205300'}, {'id': '5497', 'name': 'hamsters_break_records', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '500000'}, {'id': '5498', 'name': 'web3_game_con', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '30000'}, {'id': '5499', 'name': 'x_network_10_million', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '7700'}, {'id': '5550', 'name': 'youtube_25_million', 'lvl': '8', 'price': '154000'}, {'id': '5600', 'name': 'tg_leaders', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '121400'}, {'id': '5650', 'name': 'premarket_launch', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '1000000'}, {'id': '5700', 'name': 'hamster_kombat_merch', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '3300'}, {'id': '5750', 'name': 'ton+hamster_kombat_=_success', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '1100000'}, {'id': '5800', 'name': 'consensus_piranha_pass', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '132600'}, {'id': '5850', 'name': 'web3_academy_launch', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '153200'}, {'id': '5900', 'name': 'youtube_gold_button', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '6600'}, {'id': '5950', 'name': 'hamster_youtube_channel', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '8300'}, {'id': '6100', 'name': 'bitcoin_pizza_day', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '3700'}, {'id': '6150', 'name': 'top_10_global_ranking', 'lvl': '8', 'price': '85500'}, {'id': '6200', 'name': 'nft_collection_launch', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '93800'}, {'id': '6450', 'name': 'special_hamster_conference', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '119100'}, {'id': '6500', 'name': 'short_squeeze', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '833900'}, {'id': '6550', 'name': 'there_are_two_chairs...', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '132600'}, {'id': '6600', 'name': 'long_squeeze', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '30000'}, {'id': '6650', 'name': 'villa_for_the_dev_team', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '47700'}, {'id': '6700', 'name': 'apps_center_listing', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '82700'}, {'id': '6750', 'name': 'bogdanoff_is_calling', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '5000'}, {'id': '7000', 'name': 'usdt_on_ton', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '139300'}, {'id': '5500', 'name': 'hamster_green_energy', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '236800'}]

Список own_cards:
[{'name': 'two_factor_authentication', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'anonymous_transactions_ban', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'two_chairs', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'short_squeeze', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'notcoin_listing', 'lvl': '0'}, {'name': 'ceo_21m', 'lvl': '0'}, {'name': 'licence_japan', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_vietnam', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_turkey', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'premarket_launch', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'ceo', 'lvl': '17'}, {'name': 'it_team', 'lvl': '16'}, {'name': 'x', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'medium', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'facebook_ads', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'support_team', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'marketing', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'layerzero_listing', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'btc_pairs', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'eth_pairs', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'kyc', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'security_audition', 'lvl': '5'}, {'name': 'compliance_officer', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'influencers', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'youtube', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'product_team', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'gamefi_tokens', 'lvl': '17'}, {'name': 'top_10_cmc_pairs', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'instagram', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'tiktok', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'reddit', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'bisdev_team', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'partnership_program', 'lvl': '8'}, {'name': 'qa_team', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'antihacking_shield', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'consensys_explorer_pass', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'ux_ui_team', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'tokenomics_expert', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'risk_management_team', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'vc_labs', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'session_australia', 'lvl': '2'}, {'name': 'fan_tokens', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'defi2.0_tokens', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'kyb', 'lvl': '5'}, {'name': 'legal_opinion', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'licence_uae', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'anti_money_loundering', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'licence_asia', 'lvl': '5'}, {'name': 'licence_europe', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'licence_south_america', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'licence_australia', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'licence_nigeria', 'lvl': '8'}, {'name': 'sec_transparancy', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'licence_north_america', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'dao', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'rolex_soulmate', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'security_team', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'blocking_suspicious_accounts', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'development_hub_mumbai', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'leaderboards', 'lvl': '2'}, {'name': 'telegram_50m', 'lvl': '9'}, {'name': 'villa_for_dev_team', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'appstore_launch', 'lvl': '9'}, {'name': 'google_analytics', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'twitter_10_million', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'hamster_green_energy', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'youtube_25_million', 'lvl': '14'}, {'name': 'tg_leaders', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'hamster_drop', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'partner_announce', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'bitcoin_pizza_day', 'lvl': '9'}, {'name': 'special_hamster_conference', 'lvl': '14'}, {'name': 'top10_global', 'lvl': '14'}, {'name': 'consensys_piranja_pass', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'usdt_on_ton', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'web3_academy_launch', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'hamster_youtube_gold_button', 'lvl': '9'}, {'name': 'hamster_youtube_channel', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'apps_center_listing', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'shit_coins', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'prediction_markets', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'p2p_trading', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'trading_bots', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'staking', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'money_20_20', 'lvl': '5'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x10', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'socialfi_tokens', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x20', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x30', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x50', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'meme_coins', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'fight_fight', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'mini_game', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'dubai_office', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'data_center_tokyo', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'derivatives', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x100', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x75', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'web3_integration', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_ethiopia', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_bangladesh', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_india', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_indonesia', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_philippines', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'dex', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'oracle', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'vesting_smartcontracts', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'cx_hub_istanbul', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'nft_collection_launch', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'nft_marketplace', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'telegram_miniapp_launch', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'kamala_calling', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'bogdanoff', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'bitcoin_conference_2024', 'lvl': '8'}, {'name': 'telegram_stars_integration', 'lvl': '5'}, {'name': 'launchpad', 'lvl': '14'}, {'name': 'welcome_to_ogames', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'adv_integration_2607', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'grant_developers', 'lvl': '14'}, {'name': 'joe_rogan_podcast', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'lambo_for_ceo', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'hamster_break_records', 'lvl': '2'}, {'name': 'nft_metaverse', 'lvl': '4'}, {'name': 'ethereum_bd', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'crypto_farming', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'adv_integration_3107', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'sport_marketplace', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'market_making', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'web3_advertising', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'adv_integration_0308', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'hamstergpt', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'sleeping_hamster', 'lvl': '2'}, {'name': 'healthy_hamster', 'lvl': '4'}, {'name': 'gym_hamster', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'vipassana_hamster', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'university_hamster', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'adv_integration_0908', 'lvl': '1'}]


в списках не бывает ключей. реальный пример своего "списка" приведите.

В самих списках не бывает. А если это список словарей?

У списка словарей тоже не бывает ключей. приведите пример данных

Добавил в вопрос вывод входного массива

Я понимаю что в списках кроме как через индекс нельзя обратиться к объекту, но так как там словари я через перебор обращаюсь к словарю в котором есть ключи. Затем достаю значение и начинаю перебор второго списка словарей. Достаю из второго значение и сравниваю строки.

Вопрос не до конца ясный, что делать при повторах, если количество разное и т.п.
rec_cards=[{'id': '2450', 'name': 'fan_tokens', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '26500'}, {'id': '2500', 'name': 'staking', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '19300'}, {'id': '2550', 'name': 'btc_pairs', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '6000'}, {'id': '2600', 'name': 'eth_pairs', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '1100'}, {'id': '2650', 'name': 'top_10_cmc_pairs', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '2700'}, {'id': '2700', 'name': 'gamefi_tokens', 'lvl': '17', 'price': '2000000'}, {'id': '2750', 'name': 'defi2.0_tokens', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '1300'}, {'id': '2800', 'name': 'socialfi_tokens', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '11900'}, {'id': '2850', 'name': 'meme_coins', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '2200'}, {'id': '2900', 'name': 'shit_coins', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '18700'}, {'id': '2950', 'name': 'margin_trading_x10', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '6600'}, {'id': '3000', 'name': 'margin_trading_x20', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '34800'}, {'id': '3050', 'name': 'margin_trading_x30', 'lvl': '8', 'price': '29900'}, {'id': '3100', 'name': 'margin_trading_x50', 'lvl': '14', 'price': '3300000'}, {'id': '3150', 'name': 'margin_trading_x75', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '178700'}, {'id': '3200', 'name': 'margin_trading_x100', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '119100'}, {'id': '3250', 'name': 'derivatives', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '13800'}, {'id': '3300', 'name': 'prediction_markets', 'lvl': '8', 'price': '15000'}, {'id': '3350', 'name': 'web3_integration', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '90500'}, {'id': '3400', 'name': 'dao', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '23800'}, {'id': '3450', 'name': 'p2p_trading', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '15700'}, {'id': '3500', 'name': 'trading_bots', 'lvl': '4', 'price': '4200'}, {'id': '3550', 'name': 'layerzero_listing', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '26500'}, {'id': '4500', 'name': 'ceo', 'lvl': '19', 'price': '26800000'}, {'id': '4600', 'name': 'marketing', 'lvl': '13', 'price': '159800'}, {'id': '4550', 'name': 'it_team', 'lvl': '15', 'price': '1500000'}, {'id': '2000', 'name': 'support_team', 'lvl': '15', 'price': '543800'}, {'id': '2050', 'name': 'hamsterbook', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '11900'}, {'id': '2200', 'name': 'hamstertube', 'lvl': '11', 'price': '25700'}, {'id': '2100', 'name': 'x', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '13100'}, {'id': '2150', 'name': 'cointelegraph', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '8300'}, {'id': '2250', 'name': 'hamstergram', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '11900'}, {'id': '2300', 'name': 'tiktok', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '17900'}, {'id': '2350', 'name': 'сoindesk', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '5500'}, {'id': '2400', 'name': 'influencers', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '59600'}, {'id': '4650', 'name': 'partnership_program', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '2800'}, {'id': '4700', 'name': 'product_team', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '2700'}, {'id': '4750', 'name': 'bisdev_team', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '1300'}, {'id': '4800', 'name': 'two_factor_authentication', 'lvl': '13', 'price': '159800'}, {'id': '4850', 'name': 'ux_and_ui_team', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '18100'}, {'id': '4900', 'name': 'security_team', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '23800'}, {'id': '4950', 'name': 'qa_team', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '7000'}, {'id': '5000', 'name': 'antihacking_shield', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '5300'}, {'id': '5050', 'name': 'risk_management_team', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '11000'}, {'id': '5100', 'name': 'security_audition', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '8000'}, {'id': '5150', 'name': 'anonymous_transactions_ban', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '12500'}, {'id': '5200', 'name': 'blocking_suspicious_accounts', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '4700'}, {'id': '5250', 'name': 'tokenomics_expert', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '13300'}, {'id': '5300', 'name': 'consensus_explorer_pass', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '93300'}, {'id': '5350', 'name': 'vc_labs', 'lvl': '11', 'price': '663300'}, {'id': '5400', 'name': 'compliance_officer', 'lvl': '2', 'price': '4500'}, {'id': '5450', 'name': 'welcome_to_amsterdam', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '8000'}, {'id': '5451', 'name': 'development_hub_mumbai', 'lvl': '2', 'price': '114900'}, {'id': '5452', 'name': 'data_сenter_tokyo', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '220500'}, {'id': '5251', 'name': 'leaderboards', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '22100'}, {'id': '5453', 'name': 'minigame', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '44100'}, {'id': '3600', 'name': 'kyc', 'lvl': '15', 'price': '72600'}, {'id': '3650', 'name': 'kyb', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '1300'}, {'id': '3700', 'name': 'legal_opinion', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '3700'}, {'id': '3750', 'name': 'sec_transparancy', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '28600'}, {'id': '3800', 'name': 'anti_money_loundering', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '71500'}, {'id': '3850', 'name': 'licence_uae', 'lvl': '15', 'price': '3600000'}, {'id': '3900', 'name': 'licence_europe', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '18700'}, {'id': '3950', 'name': 'licence_asia', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '13300'}, {'id': '4000', 'name': 'licence_south_america', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '13300'}, {'id': '4050', 'name': 'licence_australia', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '18700'}, {'id': '4100', 'name': 'licence_north_america', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '37300'}, {'id': '4150', 'name': 'licence_nigeria', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '4000'}, {'id': '4200', 'name': 'licence_japan', 'lvl': '3', 'price': '77600'}, {'id': '4250', 'name': 'licence_ethiopia', 'lvl': '3', 'price': '54300'}, {'id': '4300', 'name': 'licence_india', 'lvl': '3', 'price': '69800'}, {'id': '4350', 'name': 'licence_bangladesh', 'lvl': '2', 'price': '89300'}, {'id': '4400', 'name': 'licence_indonesia', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '110300'}, {'id': '4450', 'name': 'licence_vietnam', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '93700'}, {'id': '4452', 'name': 'licence_turkey', 'lvl': '2', 'price': '95700'}, {'id': '4453', 'name': 'licence_philippines', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '165400'}, {'id': '8000', 'name': 'dex', 'lvl': '2', 'price': '95700'}, {'id': '8500', 'name': 'oracle', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '19300'}, {'id': '9500', 'name': 'vesting_smartcontracts', 'lvl': '3', 'price': '63600'}, {'id': '5460', 'name': 'hamster_with_friends', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '5000'}, {'id': '5461', 'name': 'hamster_helps_whales', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '31000'}, {'id': '5462', 'name': 'vipassana_hamster', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '9000'}, {'id': '5463', 'name': 'university_hamster', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '23000'}, {'id': '5464', 'name': 'ton_listing_on_binance', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '90000'}, {'id': '5465', 'name': 'gym_hamster', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '12000'}, {'id': '5466', 'name': 'healthy_nutrition_hamster', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '17000'}, {'id': '5467', 'name': 'sleeping_hamster', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '15000'}, {'id': '5468', 'name': 'hamstergpt', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '55000'}, {'id': '5472', 'name': 'hamsterbank', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '300000'}, {'id': '5476', 'name': 'telegram_stars_integration', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '17000'}, {'id': '5478', 'name': 'telegram_miniapp_launch', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '66300'}, {'id': '5480', 'name': 'hamster_analytics', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '82700'}, {'id': '5481', 'name': '50m_telegram_channel', 'lvl': '4', 'price': '99000'}, {'id': '5483', 'name': 'apple_appstore_launch', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '252000'}, {'id': '5484', 'name': 'rolex_for_soulmate', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '1100000'}, {'id': '5485', 'name': 'call_for_btc_to_rise', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '5000000'}, {'id': '5487', 'name': 'business_jet', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '12000000'}, {'id': '5496', 'name': 'cx_hub_istanbul', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '205300'}, {'id': '5497', 'name': 'hamsters_break_records', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '500000'}, {'id': '5498', 'name': 'web3_game_con', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '30000'}, {'id': '5499', 'name': 'x_network_10_million', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '7700'}, {'id': '5550', 'name': 'youtube_25_million', 'lvl': '8', 'price': '154000'}, {'id': '5600', 'name': 'tg_leaders', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '121400'}, {'id': '5650', 'name': 'premarket_launch', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '1000000'}, {'id': '5700', 'name': 'hamster_kombat_merch', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '3300'}, {'id': '5750', 'name': 'ton+hamster_kombat_=_success', 'lvl': '1', 'price': '1100000'}, {'id': '5800', 'name': 'consensus_piranha_pass', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '132600'}, {'id': '5850', 'name': 'web3_academy_launch', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '153200'}, {'id': '5900', 'name': 'youtube_gold_button', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '6600'}, {'id': '5950', 'name': 'hamster_youtube_channel', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '8300'}, {'id': '6100', 'name': 'bitcoin_pizza_day', 'lvl': '6', 'price': '3700'}, {'id': '6150', 'name': 'top_10_global_ranking', 'lvl': '8', 'price': '85500'}, {'id': '6200', 'name': 'nft_collection_launch', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '93800'}, {'id': '6450', 'name': 'special_hamster_conference', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '119100'}, {'id': '6500', 'name': 'short_squeeze', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '833900'}, {'id': '6550', 'name': 'there_are_two_chairs...', 'lvl': '5', 'price': '132600'}, {'id': '6600', 'name': 'long_squeeze', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '30000'}, {'id': '6650', 'name': 'villa_for_the_dev_team', 'lvl': '10', 'price': '47700'}, {'id': '6700', 'name': 'apps_center_listing', 'lvl': '7', 'price': '82700'}, {'id': '6750', 'name': 'bogdanoff_is_calling', 'lvl': '0', 'price': '5000'}, {'id': '7000', 'name': 'usdt_on_ton', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '139300'}, {'id': '5500', 'name': 'hamster_green_energy', 'lvl': '9', 'price': '236800'}]
own_cards=[{'name': 'two_factor_authentication', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'anonymous_transactions_ban', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'two_chairs', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'short_squeeze', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'notcoin_listing', 'lvl': '0'}, {'name': 'ceo_21m', 'lvl': '0'}, {'name': 'licence_japan', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_vietnam', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_turkey', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'premarket_launch', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'ceo', 'lvl': '17'}, {'name': 'it_team', 'lvl': '16'}, {'name': 'x', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'medium', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'facebook_ads', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'support_team', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'marketing', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'layerzero_listing', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'btc_pairs', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'eth_pairs', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'kyc', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'security_audition', 'lvl': '5'}, {'name': 'compliance_officer', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'influencers', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'youtube', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'product_team', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'gamefi_tokens', 'lvl': '17'}, {'name': 'top_10_cmc_pairs', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'instagram', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'tiktok', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'reddit', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'bisdev_team', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'partnership_program', 'lvl': '8'}, {'name': 'qa_team', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'antihacking_shield', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'consensys_explorer_pass', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'ux_ui_team', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'tokenomics_expert', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'risk_management_team', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'vc_labs', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'session_australia', 'lvl': '2'}, {'name': 'fan_tokens', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'defi2.0_tokens', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'kyb', 'lvl': '5'}, {'name': 'legal_opinion', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'licence_uae', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'anti_money_loundering', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'licence_asia', 'lvl': '5'}, {'name': 'licence_europe', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'licence_south_america', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'licence_australia', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'licence_nigeria', 'lvl': '8'}, {'name': 'sec_transparancy', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'licence_north_america', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'dao', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'rolex_soulmate', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'security_team', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'blocking_suspicious_accounts', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'development_hub_mumbai', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'leaderboards', 'lvl': '2'}, {'name': 'telegram_50m', 'lvl': '9'}, {'name': 'villa_for_dev_team', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'appstore_launch', 'lvl': '9'}, {'name': 'google_analytics', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'twitter_10_million', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'hamster_green_energy', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'youtube_25_million', 'lvl': '14'}, {'name': 'tg_leaders', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'hamster_drop', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'partner_announce', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'bitcoin_pizza_day', 'lvl': '9'}, {'name': 'special_hamster_conference', 'lvl': '14'}, {'name': 'top10_global', 'lvl': '14'}, {'name': 'consensys_piranja_pass', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'usdt_on_ton', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'web3_academy_launch', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'hamster_youtube_gold_button', 'lvl': '9'}, {'name': 'hamster_youtube_channel', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'apps_center_listing', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'shit_coins', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'prediction_markets', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'p2p_trading', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'trading_bots', 'lvl': '7'}, {'name': 'staking', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'money_20_20', 'lvl': '5'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x10', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'socialfi_tokens', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x20', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x30', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x50', 'lvl': '15'}, {'name': 'meme_coins', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'fight_fight', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'mini_game', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'dubai_office', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'data_center_tokyo', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'derivatives', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x100', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'margin_trading_x75', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'web3_integration', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_ethiopia', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_bangladesh', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_india', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_indonesia', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'licence_philippines', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'dex', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'oracle', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'vesting_smartcontracts', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'cx_hub_istanbul', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'nft_collection_launch', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'nft_marketplace', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'telegram_miniapp_launch', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'kamala_calling', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'bogdanoff', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'bitcoin_conference_2024', 'lvl': '8'}, {'name': 'telegram_stars_integration', 'lvl': '5'}, {'name': 'launchpad', 'lvl': '14'}, {'name': 'welcome_to_ogames', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'adv_integration_2607', 'lvl': '6'}, {'name': 'grant_developers', 'lvl': '14'}, {'name': 'joe_rogan_podcast', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'lambo_for_ceo', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'hamster_break_records', 'lvl': '2'}, {'name': 'nft_metaverse', 'lvl': '4'}, {'name': 'ethereum_bd', 'lvl': '10'}, {'name': 'crypto_farming', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'adv_integration_3107', 'lvl': '13'}, {'name': 'sport_marketplace', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'market_making', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'web3_advertising', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'adv_integration_0308', 'lvl': '12'}, {'name': 'hamstergpt', 'lvl': '11'}, {'name': 'sleeping_hamster', 'lvl': '2'}, {'name': 'healthy_hamster', 'lvl': '4'}, {'name': 'gym_hamster', 'lvl': '3'}, {'name': 'vipassana_hamster', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'university_hamster', 'lvl': '1'}, {'name': 'adv_integration_0908', 'lvl': '1'}]

list_rec_cards=[]
list_own_cards=[]

for i in rec_cards:
    list_rec_cards.append(i['name'])
for j in own_cards:
    list_own_cards.append(j['name'])


for k in list_own_cards:
    if k in list_rec_cards:
        print(f'{k}:{k}')


two_factor_authentication:two_factor_authentication
anonymous_transactions_ban:anonymous_transactions_ban
short_squeeze:short_squeeze
licence_japan:licence_japan

...

gym_hamster:gym_hamster
vipassana_hamster:vipassana_hamster
university_hamster:university_hamster


При матче делаем pop по индексу, а остатки выводим

@Freddie Нельзя удалять то, что перебираешь. Или перебирать с конца.
